# Triangle - Triangle Intersection: Coordinates

Tags: c++, math, 3d, geometry

I am implementing an algorithm by Moller on calculating  triangle triangle intersection and I cannot quite wrap my head around something:
Given two planes of the intersecting triangles, we have their corresponding equations in the form of N*P + d = 0 where N is the cross product two vectors in the plane and P is any point on the plane. d can also be calculated.

Considering the triangles are not co-planar, their intersection will be a line L = P + tD where D is the N(first plane) * N(second plane) - this is the direction of the line, P is any point on the line and t is the parameter. The algorithm stops at calculating segments of intersection of triangles with their opposing triangles' planes in terms of t. Now if these segments overlap, the triangles intersect. But again, these segments are expressed only in terms of t. I, however, want to go further and actually get the coordinates of the intersection.

So here is the question - given the two planes, three points which lie on the planes (the points of the triangles) and the line L = P + tD where we know the D and the ts, how can I calculate the points of the segments?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you

I am adding the code of what i've got so far:
    {
        //Implimentation of Tomas Moller's intesection finding algorithm with additions to determine the coorninates of the intersection

```
    //Vertex vectors
    Vector3f Va0(a.Point1.X, a.Point1.Y, a.Point1.Z);
    Vector3f Va1(a.Point2.X, a.Point2.Y, a.Point2.Z);
    Vector3f Va2(a.Point3.X, a.Point3.Y, a.Point3.Z);

    Vector3f Vb0(b.Point1.X, b.Point1.Y, b.Point1.Z);
    Vector3f Vb1(b.Point2.X, b.Point2.Y, b.Point2.Z);
    Vector3f Vb2(b.Point3.X, b.Point3.Y, b.Point3.Z);

    //First, find the plane equation of triangle b = Pb
    //N dot X + d = 0 where X is any point on the plane
    auto N2 = (Vb1 - Vb0).cross((Vb2 - Vb0));
    N2.normalize();
    float d2 = (N2 * (-1)).dot(Vb0);

    //We'll then find the signed distance from each point of the triangle a to plane Pb
    float da_0 = Round(N2.dot(Va0) + d2);
    float da_1 = Round(N2.dot(Va1) + d2);
    float da_2 = Round(N2.dot(Va2) + d2);

    //reject intersetion if none of the points lie on the plane and all have the same sign
    //meaning that the triangle a lies on one side of the triangle b
    if (da_0 != 0 && da_1 != 0 && da_2 != 0 && da_0 > 0 && da_1 > 0 && da_2 > 0)
        return nullptr;
    if (da_0 != 0 && da_1 != 0 && da_2 != 0 && da_0 < 0 && da_1 < 0 && da_2 < 0)
        return nullptr;

    //do the same thing for the other triangle
    auto N1 = (Va1 - Va0).cross((Va2 - Va0));
    N1.normalize();
    float d1 = (N1 * (-1)).dot(Va0);

    float db_0 = Round(N1.dot(Vb0) + d1);
    float db_1 = Round(N1.dot(Vb1) + d1);
    float db_2 = Round(N1.dot(Vb2) + d1);

    if (db_0 != 0 && db_1 != 0 && db_2 != 0 && db_0 > 0 && db_1 > 0 && db_2 > 0)
        return nullptr;
    if (db_0 != 0 && db_1 != 0 && db_2 != 0 && db_0 < 0 && db_1 < 0 && db_2 < 0)
        return nullptr;

    #pragma region Coplanar Triangles
    if (db_0 == 0 && db_1 == 0 && db_2 == 0)
    {
        //if the triangles are coplanar we'll find the intersection in 2d space
        return nullptr;
    }
    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region Triangles are in 3D space
    else
    {
        //Triangles are not coplanar and the intersection line is some line L = O + tD 
        //where D = N1 cross N2 - direction of the line and O is some point on it
        //We will find the the intersection segment of the first triangle with the plane os the second triangle and visa versa
        //If the two segments overlap, the triangles intesect

        auto D = N1.cross(N2);
        D.normalize();

        #pragma region Point Contact Between the Triangles
        //first reject intersection if one triangle only touches the other with one point
        if ((da_0 == 0 && da_1 > 0 && da_2 > 0) || (da_0 == 0 && da_1 < 0 && da_2 < 0))
            return nullptr;
        if ((da_0 > 0 && da_1 == 0 && da_2 > 0) || (da_0 < 0 && da_1 == 0 && da_2 < 0))
            return nullptr;
        if ((da_0 > 0 && da_1 > 0 && da_2 == 0) || (0 > da_0 && da_1 < 0 && da_2 == 0))
            return nullptr;
        if ((db_0 == 0 && db_1 > 0 && db_2 > 0) || (db_0 == 0 && db_1 < 0 && db_2 < 0))
            return nullptr;
        if ((db_0 > 0 && db_1 == 0 && db_2 > 0) || (db_0 < 0 && db_1 == 0 && db_2 < 0))
            return nullptr;
        if ((db_0 > 0 && db_1 > 0 && db_2 == 0) || (0 > db_0 && db_1 < 0 && db_2 == 0))
            return nullptr;
        #pragma endregion

        //If the above passes, proceed with 3d triangle intersection. Start with triangle a and plane Pb,
        //there will be one point of a on one side of the Pb and two points of a on the other side of Pb. Let's find them:
        #pragma region Triangle A
        tuple<Vector3f, Vector3f> edgeA1;
        tuple<Vector3f, Vector3f> edgeA2;
        float dV0 = 1;
        float dV1 = 1;
        float dV2 = 1;

        if ((da_0 > 0 && da_1 <= 0 && da_2 <= 0) || (da_0 < 0 && da_1 >= 0 && da_2 >= 0))
        {
            edgeA1 = make_tuple(Va1, Va0);
            edgeA2 = make_tuple(Va0, Va2);
            dV0 = da_1;
            dV1 = da_0;
            dV2 = da_2;
        }
        else if ((da_0 <= 0 && da_1 > 0 && da_2 <= 0) || (da_0 >= 0 && da_1 < 0 && da_2 >= 0))
        {
            edgeA1 = make_tuple(Va0, Va1);
            edgeA2 = make_tuple(Va1, Va2);
            dV0 = da_0;
            dV1 = da_1;
            dV2 = da_2;
        }
        else if ((da_0 <= 0 && da_1 <= 0 && da_2 > 0) || (da_0 >= 0 && da_1 >= 0 && da_2 < 0))
        {
            edgeA1 = make_tuple(Va0, Va2);
            edgeA2 = make_tuple(Va2, Va1);
            dV0 = da_0;
            dV1 = da_2;
            dV2 = da_1;
        }

        //pi = D * Vi where i = 0, 1, 2
        auto pA_0 = D.dot(get<0>(edgeA1));
        auto pA_1 = D.dot(get<0>(edgeA2));
        auto pA_2 = D.dot(get<1>(edgeA2));

        //The tA_1 and tA_2 define the interval of the intersection of triangle a with the line L
        float tA_1 = pA_0 + (pA_1 - pA_0) * (dV0 / (dV0 - dV1));
        float tA_2 = pA_1 + (pA_2 - pA_1) * (dV1 / (dV1 - dV2));
        #pragma endregion

        //Now repeat for triangle b
        #pragma region Triangle B
        tuple<Vector3f, Vector3f> edgeB1;
        tuple<Vector3f, Vector3f> edgeB2;

        if ((db_0 > 0 && db_1 <= 0 && db_2 <= 0) || (db_0 < 0 && db_1 >= 0 && db_2 >= 0))
        {
            edgeB1 = make_tuple(Vb1, Vb0);
            edgeB2 = make_tuple(Vb0, Vb2);
            dV0 = db_1;
            dV1 = db_0;
            dV2 = db_2;
        }
        else if ((db_0 <= 0 && db_1 > 0 && db_2 <= 0) || (db_0 >= 0 && db_1 < 0 && db_2 >= 0))
        {
            edgeB1 = make_tuple(Vb0, Vb1);
            edgeB2 = make_tuple(Vb1, Vb2);
            dV0 = db_0;
            dV1 = db_1;
            dV2 = db_2;
        }
        else if ((db_0 <= 0 && db_1 <= 0 && db_2 > 0) || (db_0 >= 0 && db_1 >= 0 && db_2 < 0))
        {
            edgeB1 = make_tuple(Vb0, Vb2);
            edgeB2 = make_tuple(Vb2, Vb1);
            dV0 = db_0;
            dV1 = db_2;
            dV2 = db_1;
        }

        //pi = D * Vi where i = 0, 1, 2
        auto pB_0 = D.dot(get<0>(edgeB1));
        auto pB_1 = D.dot(get<0>(edgeB2));
        auto pB_2 = D.dot(get<1>(edgeB2));

        //The tA_1 and tA_2 define the interval of the intersection of triangle a with the line L
        float tB_1 = pB_0 + (pB_1 - pB_0) * (dV0 / (dV0 - dV1));
        float tB_2 = pB_1 + (pB_2 - pB_1) * (dV1 / (dV1 - dV2));
        #pragma endregion

        #pragma region Determine Overlap
        bool intersect = false;
        float intPoint1;
        float intPoint2;

        //Order the segments
        if (tA_1 > tA_2)
        {
            float temp = tA_1;
            tA_1 = tA_2;
            tA_2 = temp;
        }
        if (tB_1 > tB_2)
        {
            float temp = tB_1;
            tB_1 = tB_2;
            tB_2 = temp;
        }

        //Check for overlap
        if (tB_1 >= tA_1 && tB_2 <= tA_2)
        {
            intPoint1 = tB_1;
            intPoint2 = tB_2;
            intersect = true;
        }
        else if (tA_1 >= tB_1 && tA_2 <= tB_2)
        {
            intPoint1 = tA_1;
            intPoint2 = tA_2;
            intersect = true;
        }
        else if (tB_1 >= tA_1 && tB_1 < tA_2 && tB_2 > tA_2)
        {
            intPoint1 = tB_1;
            intPoint2 = tA_2;
            intersect = true;
        }
        else if (tA_1 >= tB_1 && tA_1 < tB_2 && tA_2 > tB_2)
        {
            intPoint1 = tA_1;
            intPoint2 = tB_2;
            intersect = true;
        }
        #pragma endregion

        if (!intersect)
            return nullptr;

        //If an overlap found, perform the last step of the algorithm and find the actual points of the intersection segment
        else
        {

        }
    }
    #pragma endregion 
}
```

Comment: please add your code as edit in your question so that people could help you on the basis of your effort, otherwise people would not do your homework here!

Comment: This is easy: the common intersection is covered by the range of t that overlap, i.e. [max(tA1, tB1), min(tA2, tB2)], unless empty. The intersection points are given by the corresponding P+tD.

Comment: Your code looks more complicated than needs be. For instance, the check for overlap can be written more simply max(tA1, tB1) < min(tA2, tB2).

Comment: OK... so in the L = P+tD we know the D and ts. How do we find the P then? Thanks